# Yii2 Pjax form to update div's with ID

Tags: php, yii, yii2, pjax

I have a form that looks like this

```php
<?php      
    \yii\widgets\Pjax::begin(['id' => 'calculator-pjax']);
    $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'id' => $model->formName(),
        'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
        'enableClientValidation'=> false,
        'validateOnBlur' => false,
        'validateOnChange' => false,
        'validateOnSubmit' => false,
        'options' => ['autocomplete' => 'off', 'data-pjax' => true],
    ]);
?>
...
...
<?= $form->field($model,'tax',
                ['template' => '
                {label}
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    {input}
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <span class="input-group-text">%</span>
                    </div>
                    {error}
                </div>
                {hint}
                '])->textInput(['class' => 'form-control form-control-lg']); ?>
<?= Html::submitButton(Module::t('app', 'Calculate'), array('buttonType'=>'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-lg')); ?>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); \yii\widgets\Pjax::end(); ?>

<div id="tax1"> <!-- Jquery update here --> </div>
<div id="tax2"> <!-- Jquery update here --> </div>
<div id="tax2"> <!-- Jquery update here --> </div>
```

my javascript ajax post looks like this

```
            $(document).ready(function () {  
                var $form = $("#<?= $model->formName() ?>");
                $form.on("submit", function (event, messages) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopImmediatePropagation(); 
                    $.ajax({
                        "type":"POST",
                        "url":$form.attr('action'),
                        "data":$form.serialize(),
                        "dataType":"json",
                        "cache": true, 
                        "success":function(data){
                            $("#tax1").html(data.tax);
                            $("#tax2").html(data.tax2); 
                            $("#tax3").html(data.tax3);     
                        }                    
                    });
                    return false;       
                });
            });
```

below is calculator action that returns a json

```
class calculatorAction extends Action
{
    public function run()
    {
                $model = new calculator;
        $model->scenario = calculator::SCENARIO_TAX;

        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

            if ($model->validate())
            {
                             $this->calculatetax();
                             die;
            }
            else
            {
                Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
                return ActiveForm::validate($model);
            }

        } else {

            return $this->controller->render('calculator', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

When I submit an empty form, I noticed in my console the ajax post it show the error, but it doesn't reflect on the `<form>`, instead it replaces the whole form the the error json

`{ "calculator-tax": [ "Tax cannot be blank." ] }`

Any idea what causes this or how to stop it from doing so? and how to update the `<div>` with the update calculation results. thanks.